# cannot install functools32 on google colab

Tags: python, setuptools, google-colaboratory, functools

I'm new to ML/DL and using google colab as my DL tool. I'm currently trying to setup [tensorflow/HED](https://github.com/moabitcoin/holy-edge/blob/master/README.md) on google colab. When I ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I got an error like

```
Collecting functools32==3.2.3.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/60/6ac26ad05857c601308d8fb9e87fa36d0ebf889423f47c3502ef034365db/functools32-3.2.3-2.tar.gz  
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-zhhba6da/functools32/"
```

I've updated setuptools to the newest version 
(`Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (40.8.0)`). It however doesn't seem solve the issue.

Google colab uses python 3.6.7.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @Infected Drake: yes, that is the only error message shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[functools32](https://github.com/MiCHiLU/python-functools32#readme) is a backport of the Python 3.2 functools module for use on Python versions 2.7. It shouldn't be installed for Python 3.6.